# Airprint - direct to another uiview after print job is finished

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, printing, airprint

I have successfully incorporated AirPrint functionality in my iOS application (iPad application to be more specific). However, I can't work out how to programmatically direct the user to another view when the print job is complete.

I have a print button in my application which allowed users to print a label and I have tried the following two approaches which have both failed:

1. Use presentViewController after printToPrinter

   var defaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
   var printerURL:NSURL = defaults.URLForKey("DefaultPrinter")!
   var printer:UIPrinter = UIPrinter(URL: printerURL)
   printController.printToPrinter(printer, completionHandler:nil)

   var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC") as HomeController
   self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

With the code above, I am able to print to the printer but the app throws an exception on the self.presentViewController call. I noticed that the AirPrint print status popover is still visible when the app tries to present the Home view.

2. Use completion handler of printToPrinter

   printController.printToPrinter(printer, completionHandler:  {
       (controller:UIPrintInteractionController!, completed:Bool, error:NSError!) -> Void in
       var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AppSettingsVC") as AppSettingsController
       self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   });

I have a similar issue as method 1 - I get the AirPrint popover showing the print status. But the exception is thrown on the presentViewController line. When I set a debug points, I notice that the app tries to present the Home view when the AirPrint popover is still visible.

I would have thought it will be quite simple, but I must be missing something trivial here! Basically the logic I am trying to implement is as follows:
1. User clicks the Print button
2. App prints a label using AirPrint
3. Once the label has been printed (ie the AirPrint status popover has closed), the app needs direct the user to the Home view

Can someone please assist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue in that there seems to be no way to tell when the iOS airprint "printing to pritner..." white alertbox is finished (ie. closes). I tried UIAlertViewDelegate and UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate and none of the methods are hit :(